# liferay : rendering <portlet:renderURL> in custom taglib

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, portlet, taglib

want to create a link to other pages of portlet in my own **taglib** with `out.print()` but in execution liferay can't render `<portlet:renderURL>` taglibs : 
taglib code :

```
    int counter = 0;
    while (rs.next()) {
        counter++;
        int spcPk = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("tCommodityGroupSpcPK"));
         result = "<tr>" +
                "        <td id=\"group-"+counter+"\">" +
                "            <a href=\"<portlet:renderURL><portlet:param name='jspPage'" +
                "             value='subGroup.jsp?p1="+spcPk+"'  /></portlet:renderURL>\" /> " +
                "       "+rs.getString("xa")+"    " +
                "            </a> " +
                "        </td> " +
                "        <td id=\"group-"+counter+"\">"+rs.getString("xx")+"</td> " +
                "        <td id=\"group-"+counter+"\">"+rs.getString("aa")+"</td> " +
                "        <td id=\"group-"+counter+"\">"+rs.getString("Result")+"</td> " +
                "    </tr>";

        out.print(result);

    }
    rs.close();
   // out.println(result);
    cstmt.close();
```

**in execution of view.jsp   and other tags has been rendered successfully but the liferay taglibs don't .. when i click on links i have somthing like this in my url !!**

```
localhost:8081/%3Cportlet:renderURL%3E%3Cportlet:param%20name='jspPage'%20value='subGroup.jsp?p1=3'%20/%3E%3C/portlet:renderURL%3E
```

can anybody help me in rendering that taglibs in custom taglib class ?

Answer (score 0):

Thats obvious, `JSP Engine` consider your tag as any other markup.
You have to use the `API` rather than `Tag` like mentioned below

```
PortletURL portletURL = renderResponse.createRenderURL();
portletURL.setParameter("jspPage", "subGroup.jsp?p1="+spcPk);
```

then inject `portletURL.toString()` into the markup

### UPDATE:

You should have access to both `renderRequest` and `renderResponse` implicitly if you define `<portlet:defineObjects />` in your `JSP`.

The other way to get them from normal `request` object is

```
PortletResponse portletResponse = (PortletResponse)request.getAttribute(JavaConstants.JAVAX_PORTLET_RESPONSE);
```

You can refer to the source code of any of the existing `Liferay UI` Tags like `asset-categories-navigation` for more information.

Comment: the problem is i can't access to renderRequest and renderResponse in my java class .